# Generate hOCR from Microsoft Computer Vision OCR

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr, hocr

I'm using the Microsoft Read API to derive OCR data from local images. My script is based on this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-hand-text?tabs=version-2.

While I can obtain the OCR data in JSON format, I would like to get the output as hOCR. I found this resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-search-power-skills/azure-hocr-generator-sample/. It's not clear to me how to implement this in relation to the Python script in the tutorial.

Does anybody know how to convert the JSON output to hOCR?

Comment: which version of Read API are you using.The 3.0 API has:

Improved accuracy,
Confidence scores for words,
Support for both Spanish and English with the additional language parameter,
A different output format

Comment: I've been using 2.1 and will look into 3.0. Still hoping someone can offer an hOCR conversion.

Comment: would it help if I gave you a parser to convert JSON to dataframe which has all the words, their coordinates (x,y,w,h) and confidence as columns?

Comment: Thanks Sreekiran but I've written something similar to that for other use cases. Now, I'm looking for either hOCR or ALTO formats so that the text can be edited in a human readable way in Oxygen XML Editor.